# Weird array logic when switching reference and offset

Tags: c, pointers

I was experimenting some stuff with pointers in my school today when i found that the following code would output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Here is the code:

```
int foo[10];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
foo[i] = i;

for (i= 0; i < 10; i++)
printf("%d\n", i[foo]);
```

I have been looking for an explanation on the internet but I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `i[foo]` is interpreted by your compiler as `*(i + foo)` which is the same than `foo[i] ( *(foo +i) )`.
So your are printing the `foo[i]`'s
Note that `*(foo + i)` does point to the correct address because of the pointer arithmetic system. When you add a number A to a pointer, your are actually adding `A*sizeof(*your_pointer)`